# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Estoy creando un programa para ordenar una lista de numeros.

Sin embargo, el programa me devuelve:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Este es mi código:

```
number_list=[]

list_lenght=int(input("List lenght: "))

while len(number_list)<list_lenght:
    item=input("Enter new item to the list:")
    number_list.append(item)
    print(number_list)

print("That's your number list: ",number_list)

number_list_final=[]

def order_number_list(number_list):
    i=0
    i2=i+1
    while (i2)<=(len(number_list)):
        while number_list[i]<=number_list[i2]:
            i2=i2+1
        i=i2
        i2=i+1
    final_item=number_list[i]
    number_list_final.append(final_item)
    del number_list[i] 
    order_number_list(number_list)

order_number_list(number_list)
print(number_list_final)
```

¿Alguien sabe el motivo?

Comment: bueno iría bien que nos indicaras cuáles son tus hipótesis, así como cómo lanzas este script. Que hagas un poco de debugging tú mismo, vaya :)

Comment: Mi conocimiento hasta el momento es muy limitado. A partir de ahi, lo que yo deduzco es que hay algun problema a la hora de indexar la lista, con la variable de bucle "i". Me extraña porque yo le asigno un valor a "i" y a "i2", por lo que el programa tendria que hacer la comparación correctamente, tratandose de dos componentes de mi lista, siendo integers ambos.
Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este fragmento de código:

```
while i2 <= len(number_list):
    while number_list[i] <= number_list[i2]:
        i2 = i2+1
```

En el primer `while`, `i2` alcanza finalmente como valor un índice que no existe. Tienes que cambiar la condición para evitar el último valor.

Por otro lado, el segundo `while` está incrementando `i2` sin comprobar si se ha llegado al final de la lista.

Así mismo, la lista que pasas como argumento se altera en el proceso perdiendo elementos a medida que haces `del number_list[i]`. Irremediablemente llegará un momento en que la lista esté vacía y que este `del` produzca error.

Suponiendo que quieras hacerte tu propio algorimo de ordenación, sin usar facilidades de python como `sorted`, `min` ó `max`, aún así déjame aconsejarte un par de cosillas:

- Nunca, nunca, nunca uses variables externas como resultado de una función. Toda función debería devolver su resultado mediante `return`
- Usa `for` antes que `while` para recorrer una lista
- Modificar una lista mientras se está procesando suele ser la causa de numerosos errores. La lista que pasas para ordenar es destruida dentro de la función, acortándose en longitud y perdiendo elementos.

Manteniendo la función como *recursiva* (que no sería necesario), una posible reescritura sería así:

```
def order_number_list(number_list):

    if len(number_list) == 0:
        return number_list
    else:
        m = number_list[0]

        for i in range(1, len(number_list)):
            if m > number_list[i]:
                m = number_list[i]

        return [m] + order_number_list(number_list[1:])

number_list_final = order_number_list(number_list)
```

Aunque sin recursión está mejor:

```
def order_number_list(number_list):

    lst = number_list[:]  # copia de la lista

    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        for j in range(i, len(lst)): 
            if lst[i] > lst[j]:
                lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]

    return lst
```

Comment: No podria haber pedido una respuesta más completa, muchisimas gracias.

Comment: I perdona la contrarespuesta pero, en el primer **while**, si hubiese puesto (len(number_list)-1) seria correcto cierto? Porque asi "i2" alcanzaría un valor real.

Olvidé que los labels de las listas solo llegan a lenght -1

Comment: Así es. con `len(number_list)-1` no daría error.

Answer (score 1):

en el primer while del metodo **order_number_list** cambia la condicion<= solo por menor.

lo que pasa es que estas consultando una posición fuera del rango de la lista con la instrucción **number_list[i2]**

Comment: Hola, y gracias por responder.

El error se produce en la siguiente linea, es decir en el segundo **while** del metodo **order_number_list**.

Y, creo que el error no viene por los comparadores sino que algo pasa con la lista y su rango, que al evaluar sus componentes, da error.

Answer (score 0):

recuerda que en Python los arreglos comienzan desde el indice 0.
Luego, por ejemplo, este arreglo: [1,54,23,6] tiene 4 elementos, pero el 1 está en el indice 0, el 54 en el 1, el 23 en el 2 y el 6 en el 3.
Luego, cuando haces:

```
    while (i2)<=(len(number_list)): ...
```

El ultimo valor de i2 será el número de elementos de la lista (en nuestro ejemplo 4), sin embargo sabemos que el indice 4 no existe ! Ya que solo llega hasta el 3 (desde el 0).

Luego la solución es cambiar la condición ya sea por:

```
    while (i2) <= (len(number_list) - 1): ...
```

o por:

```
    while (i2) < (len(number_list)): ...
```

Espero haber ayudado :)

Answer (score 0):

lo que normalmente hago cuando quiero eliminar elementos de una lista es trabajar con una copia y un contador.

```
contador = 0
lista = [(1, '2020/04/02', '23:24'), (2, '2020/04/02', '23:42'), (2, '2020/04/26', '16:40'), (4, '2020/04/03', '17:00')]
```

Ahora, deseo eliminar de la lista las tuplas cuyo primer elemento sea 2.

```
for tupla in lista[:]:
    if tupla[0] == 2:
        del lista[contador]
    else:contador += 1
```

El truco está en aumentar el contador solamente cuando no se elimine un elemento para no obtener:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Cualquier sugerencia será apreciada.