# IndexError: list index out of range al intentar recorrer lista

Tags: python

Este código halla el máximo número de repeticiones de un elemento de una lista y va eliminando a los que sean diferentes del número que más se repite, y al final debo imprimir él numeró de veces que elimine para que mi lista me quede igual.

```
from statistics import mode
v=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
mr=mode(v)
w=len(v)
c=0
for i in range(w):
    if v[i]!= mr :
        v.remove(v[i])
        c=c+1
print(c)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [IndexError: list index out of range](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44682/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range)

Answer (score 2):

Cuando eliminas un elemento de la lista invalidas el rango de índices. Inicialmente tu lista tendrá `len(v)` elementos, con un rango de índices desde 0 hasta `len(v) - 1`, si eliminas un elemento `len(v) - 1` ya no será un índice válido porque la lista tiene un item menos, pero el `for - range` intentará indizar con él, causando la excepción.

Generalmente no es buena idea eliminar items de un iterable mientras se itera, aunque hay formas seguras de hacerlo, la más simple iterar en orden inverso:

```
from statistics import mode


v = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
mr = mode(v)

for i in range(len(v) - 1, -1, -1):
    if v[i] != mr :
        del v[i]
        c = c + 1
print(c)
```

No obstante, no necesitas ni tiene sentido eliminar nada de la lista, basta con que cuentes el número de elementos distintos a la moda:

```
from statistics import mode


v = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
mr = mode(v)

c = 0
for num in v:
    if num != mr:
        c = c + 1

print(c)
```

O más simple aún, usando `sum` y una expresión generadora:

```
from statistics import mode


v = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
mr = mode(v)
c = sum(num != mr for num in v) 
print(c)
```

O cuenta las veces que aparece la moda y restalo a la longitud de la lista:

```
from statistics import mode


v = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
mr = mode(v)
c = len(v) - v.count(mr)
print(c)
```

O puedes usar `collections.Counter` para conocer directamente cuantas veces aparece:

```
from collections import Counter

v = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
moda, apariciones = Counter(v).most_common(1)[0]
c = len(v) - apariciones
print(c)
```