# Python me marca IndexError: list index out of range, aún así genera la lista que quiero hacer, ¿Porque ocurre?

Tags: python

Agradecería enormemente si alguien me podría ayudar.
Estoy listando datos de un texto (alturas.txt) que posee datos escritos de esta forma:

10/01/2019 00:01:00.52  0.70577

Con los cuales estoy generando una lista con el siguiente código:

```
texto = open('alturas.txt')

ti = 60.52
for linea in texto:                                
    valores = linea.split()                                                                    
    tiempo = valores[1].split(':')                      
    altura = float(valores[2])                        
    hora = float(tiempo[0])                               
    minuto = float(tiempo[1])                            
    segundo = float(tiempo[2])                       
    dt = segundo + minuto*60 + hora*3600 - ti            
    tupla = (dt,altura)                                  
    datos.append(tupla)                                 
    
texto.close()'''

y pese a que se genera la lista, me arroja este error:
 File '########', line 6, in <module>
    tiempo = valores[1].split(':')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Esta línea corresponde a tiempo = valores[1].split(':'), pero la lista valores debiese tener 3 elementos, por lo que el segundo elemento (1) no debiese producir ese error.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [IndexError: list index out of range](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44682/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range)

Comment: El problema es que hay un momento en el que llegas a un `string` que no cumple con tus requisitos de `.split()` por lo tanto cuando hace el `.split()` no te separa nada y no tienes el indice `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mira te recomiendo que utilizes el modulo 're' de python

```
import re
```

Supongamos que tienes este texto:

```
texto = "10/01/2019 00:01:00:52 0.70577"
```

Entonces separamos los distintos fragmentos de la cadena para trabajar con mayor comodidad:

```
fechaRe = re.findall('[0-9/]{10,}', texto)
print(fechaRe)

tiempoRe = re.findall('[0-9:]{11,}', texto)
print(tiempoRe)

valorRe = re.findall('[0-9.]{6,}', texto)
print(valorRe)
```

La función que realiza 're.findall' es buscar todos los caracteres que estén dentro de los [ ]

Ejemplo: `[0-9/]`<- busca todos los numeros entre el 0 y el 9, y el simbolo '/' en cadenas que tengan un largo `{10,}` caracteres.

Y la salida te da una lista:

```
Salida: ['10/01/2019']
```

Y si quieres almacenar los datos como cadena:

```
fechaString = fechaRe[0]
print(fechaString)

>> Salida: 10/01/2019

tiempoString = tiempoRe[0]
print(tiempoString)

>> Salida: 00:01:00:52
```

Y como ultimo si quieres ir separando el string en varias partes

```
print(tiempoString[:2])
>> Salida: 00
print(tiempoString[3:][:-6])
>> Salida: 01
print(tiempoString[6:][:-3])
>> Salida: 00
print(tiempoString[-2:])
>> Salida: 52
```