# Me salta este error en mi programa: apellidos.append(nombre_apellido[1]) IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo este código pero me sale error al final. ¿Qué puedo hacer para evitarlo? Se supone que mi código debe de decir si el nombre que se escoge es compatible con el apellido.  Para ello están los siguientes criterios:

1. Ambos nombre y apellido tienen la misma cantidad de letras ---> 10 ptos.
2. Ambos nombre y apellido empiezan con una vocal o ambos empiezan con una consonante ---> 5 ptos.
3. Ambos nombre y apellido tienen el mismo número de vocales ---> 10 ptos.
4. Ambos nombre y apellido terminan con la exacta misma letra ---> 20 ptos.
   Mientras más puntos obtenga, más compatible es el nombre.

Anteriormente formulé unas preguntas similares, pero ahora cambié el código completamente. El código debería de estar bien pero salen errores al final. ¿Como los corrijo?

```
print('Ingrese los cinco nombres que le gustan para su bebé:')
nom1= input('1.' )
nom2= input('2.' )
nom3= input('3.' )
nom4= input('4.' )
nom5= input('5.' )
apellido = input('Ingrese el apellido del bebé:')

nombres = [nom1+(' ')+apellido, nom2+(' ')+apellido, nom3+(' ')+apellido, nom4+(' ')+apellido, 
nom5+(' ')+apellido]

print ('---------menú-----------')
print ('1.', nom1, apellido)
print ('2.', nom2, apellido)
print ('3.', nom3, apellido)
print ('4.', nom4, apellido)
print ('5.', nom5, apellido)
print ('------------------------')


def criterio1(nombre, apellido):
    if len(nombre) == len(apellido):
        return 10
    else:
        return 0


def criterio2(nombre, apellido):
    nombre = nombre.lower()     
    apellido = apellido.lower()

    vocales = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    nombre_es_vocal = nombre[0] in vocales  
    apellido_es_vocal = apellido[0] in vocales  

    if nombre_es_vocal == apellido_es_vocal:
        return 5
    else:
        return 0


def criterio3(nombre, apellido):
    nombre = nombre.lower()     
    apellido = apellido.lower()

    vocales = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    vocal_nombre = 0
    vocal_apellido = 0

    for letra in nombre:    
        if letra in vocales:
            vocal_nombre += 1

for letra in apellido: 
    if letra in vocales:
        vocal_apellido += 1

    if vocal_nombre == vocal_apellido:
        return 10
    else:
        return 0

 
def criterio4(nombre, apellido):
    nombre = nombre.lower()     
    apellido = apellido.lower()

    if nombre[-1] == apellido[-1]:
        return 20
    else:
        return 0


def preparar_data(lista):
    nombres = []
    apellidos = []

    for nombre_completo in lista:
        nombre_apellido = nombre_completo.split(' ') 

        nombres.append(nombre_apellido[0])
        apellidos.append(nombre_apellido[1])

     return nombres, apellidos


def evaluar(nombres, apellidos):
     for nombre, apellido in zip(nombres, apellidos):
        resultado = criterio1(nombre, apellido)     
        resultado += criterio2(nombre, apellido)
        resultado += criterio3(nombre, apellido)
        resultado += criterio4(nombre, apellido)

        print('La compatibilidad entre ' + nombre + ' y ' + apellido + ' es: ' + str(resultado))
    

lista = []
for i in range(5):
    print('Ingrese opción número: ' + str(i+1))
    lectura = input()

     assert len(lectura.split()) == 2, 'No ingreso un Nombre y un Apellido'
     assert lectura.split()[0].isalpha(), 'El nombre no esta conformado por letras'
     assert lectura.split()[1].isalpha(), 'El nombre no esta conformado por letras'

    lista.append(lectura)

nombres,apellidos = preparar_data(lista)

assert len(nombres) == len(apellidos), 'No ingreso los nombres correctamente, ingrese un nombre y apellido por opcion'

evaluar(nombres, apellidos)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [IndexError: list index out of range](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44682/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range)

Comment: ¿cómo aplico eso a mi código? ¿Me podría dar una idea?

Comment: ¿Son compañeros con [No entiendo las variables y las funciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/438144/no-entiendo-las-variables-y-las-funciones)?

Comment: Sí somos compañeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el código que necesitas es el que ahora mismo está en la pregunta, los únicos errores que tiene son de identación. Chequeá bien eso. Las líneas 87; 105; 106; 107; y de la 57 a 64, que tienen que estar dentro de la función `def criterio3(nombre, apellido):`.